# An error on GetMainWindow function FlaUI C#

Tags: c#, automation, ui-automation, flaui

I'm using FlaUI library to automate desktop app.

I took an error on try to run code to take a window of launched program. Error: Could not find process with id: ***'

Details of error.

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Could not find process with id: 13536
  Source=FlaUI.Core
  StackTrace:
   at FlaUI.Core.Application.FindProcess(Int32 processId)
   at FlaUI.Core.Application.<WaitWhileMainHandleIsMissing>b__33_0()
   at FlaUI.Core.Tools.Retry.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<WhileTrue>b__0()
   at FlaUI.Core.Tools.Retry.While[T](Func`1 retryMethod, Func`2 checkMethod, Nullable`1 timeout, Nullable`1 interval, Boolean throwOnTimeout, Boolean ignoreException, String timeoutMessage, Boolean lastValueOnTimeout, T defaultOnTimeout)
   at FlaUI.Core.Application.WaitWhileMainHandleIsMissing(Nullable`1 waitTimeout)
   at FlaUI.Core.Application.GetMainWindow(AutomationBase automation, Nullable`1 waitTimeout)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\jekug\source\repos\FlaUI test\FlaUI test\Program.cs:line 10

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
```

ArgumentException: Process with an Id of 13536 is not running.

What can be wrong and are there other ways to take
a window in FlaUI?

Thank you
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

calc.exe on any newer windows is actually just a proxy executable to in the end run the "WindowsStoreApp" calculator which behaves quite differently. For those apps, you need to use `LaunchStoreApp` instead of `Launch` in order to get the correct process.